# I am getting an error in eclipse while working on jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

While Compiling the JDBC PROGRAM I AM GETTING THIS ERROR

**PROGRAM CODE**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection conn=null;
        Statement stat=null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn =  (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cricket","root","root");
            stat = ((java.sql.Connection) conn).createStatement();
            rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT Cric_id,Cric_name,Normal_Skilla,Special_Skill,Other_Skill FROM indian");

            while(rs.next())
            {
                int id = rs.getInt("Cric_id");
                String name = rs.getString("Cric_name");
                String normal = rs.getString("Normal_Skills");
                String special = rs.getString("Special_Skill");
                String other = rs.getString("Other_Skill");

                System.out.println(id +"\t"+name+"\t"+normal+"\t"+special+"\t"+other);
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error:"+e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if(conn != null)
                try{
                    conn.close();
                }catch(Exception ig)
                {
                    System.out.println("ERROR2:"+ig);
                }
        }

    }

}
```

**ERROR**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JDBC1 (wrong name: jdbc1)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I am Using Eclipse IDE can anyone see to it that where the hell i am wrong

Comment: What's the name of the class and how are you invoking the program?

Answer (score 0):

There is no column named `Normal_Skills` at your query.
Change from

```
  String normal = rs.getString("Normal_Skills");
```

To

```
  String normal = rs.getString("Normal_Skilla");
```

or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Thats probably because you are not having the jar file for the driver you have selected in code.

for "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", download the jar file with this driver and add to the project and try to execute again.

you can download jar from http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cricket","root","root");
            stat = conn.createStatement();
            rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT Cric_id,Cric_name,Normal_Skilla,Special_Skill,Other_Skill FROM indian");
```